# Variable value of feature1 -> feature 2 through call read

Tags: karate

In this case, I have 2 feature files

1) create-user.feature

2) redeem-create.feature

I have created new feature i.e redeem.feature to integrate both the features.

In redeem.feature,i’m not using any back ground step and created the scenario step as below

scenario: Run create user

```
# fetch service token (redemption endpoints are protected by service token)
* def result = call read('classpath:com/imscreateuser/create-user.feature')
* print "testing ..."+ result.teacher
* def idval = result.teacher
* print idval
* def signIn = call read('classpath:com/redeem/redeem-create.feature') { username: idval }
```

I have below scenario in redeem-create.feature

@ignore

Feature: re-usable feature to create a single cat

Scenario:

```
* def result = call read('classpath:com/ims/fetch-
rrc2servicetoken.feature')
Given url 'https://aps-il-test.io/api/redemptions'
And header Accept = 'application/json'
And request { userId: '#(username)' }
When method post
Then status 200
* print response.subscriptionId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure), I quote below:

> Variables set using `def` in the `Background` will be re-set before every
>   `Scenario`. If you are looking for a way to do something only once per
>   `Feature`, take a look at `callonce`. On the other hand, if you are
>   expecting a variable in the `Background` to be modified by one `Scenario`
>   so that later ones can see the updated value - that is not how you
>   should think of them, and you should combine your 'flow' into one
>   scenario. Keep in mind that you should be able to comment-out a
>   `Scenario` or skip some via tags without impacting any others.

EDIT: ok after you edited your question, does this help:

```
* def signIn = call read('classpath:com/redeem/redeem-create.feature') { username: '#(idval)' }
```

Please take the time to understand Embedded Expressions: https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

And Karate expressions: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions

Comment: In this case, i'm not using back ground step. I have updated the question with clear steps. In Scenario feature, variable persisted in  **call read feature** can pass as parameter to next **call read feature**

Comment: @VinodKumar my point is you cannot have one `Scenario` depend on another `Scenario`. read the above *carefully* please.

Comment: @VinodKumar ok I think I finally understand your question, just edited.

Comment: Thanks Peter, it worked, I made some changes with above step in feature

*  string username1 = username
* def requestBody = { "userId": '#(username1)', "locale": '#(localevalue)' }
* string payload = requestBody